# Soundcloud HTML5 Player not loading in Firefox

Tags: html, flash, soundcloud

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.2 running Firefox 18 and I'm not able to get the HTML5 Soundcloud player to work. I get blank space where it should be, and "Additional plugins are required to display all the media on this page" shows up at the top of the page. If I click that, it prompts for Macromedia Flash.

I'm working locally, but the same is true here:

http://blog.soundcloud.com/2011/11/03/html5/

I don't have any extensions, so I'm not sure what the issue could be?

Per some advice, I added an htaccess file with the following, which didn't work:

```
AddType audio/ogg oga ogg
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, since Firefox doesn't yet have mp3 support, we have to rely on Flash plugin in order to play music there. That's the reason why widget doesn't initialise for you.

Comment: Firefox is unlikely to ever have MP3 support, same goes for Opera.

Comment: Soundcloud doesn't have the know-how to convert it so it works?